# Changing code to search for new folders instead of old - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm pretty new to this website and fairly poor in VB.NET and usually can just modify codes myself, but not this time. So I was wondering how I would convert this code to search for the newest folder instead of the oldest folder. Thanks in advance!

```
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Examples\")
    Dim dirs() As DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()
    Dim creationTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim oldestDir As DirectoryInfo

    For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In dirs
        If DateTime.Compare(dir.CreationTime(), creationTime) < 0 Then
            oldestDir = dir
            creationTime = dir.CreationTime()
        End If
        TextBox5.Text = oldestDir.FullName
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to start with an intial creationTime of `DateTime.MinValue` and reverse the operator used in the date comparison (from `<` to `>`).  (I also changed the name of the variable from `oldestDir` to `newestDir`.)

```
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Examples\")
    Dim dirs() As DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()
    Dim creationTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
    Dim newestDir As DirectoryInfo = Nothing

    For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In dirs
        If DateTime.Compare(dir.CreationTime(), creationTime) > 0 Then
            newestDir = dir
            creationTime = dir.CreationTime()
        End If
    Next

    If newestDir IsNot Nothing Then
        TextBox5.Text = newestDir.FullName
    End If
```

EDIT: I would also recommend doing the textbox update once, at the end of the loop, instead of on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks. This worked! I would Vote Up but it requires 15 Rep Points ):

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a function like this?

```
 Public Function GetOldestOrNewestFileFullPath(ByVal path As String, Optional ByVal getLatest As Boolean = True) As String
    If Not Directory.Exists(path) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException
    End If

    Dim parent As New DirectoryInfo(path)
    Dim children() As FileInfo = parent.GetFiles

    If children.Length <= 0 Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim oldestOrLatest As FileInfo = children(0)
    If getLatest Then
        For Each child In children.Skip(1)
            If child.CreationTime > oldestOrLatest.CreationTime Then
                oldestOrLatest = child
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For Each child In children.Skip(1)
            If child.CreationTime < oldestOrLatest.CreationTime Then
                oldestOrLatest = child
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return oldestOrLatest.FullName
End Function
```